# Spring cloud gateway auto routing with eureka

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I work with Spring to create microservices. I am using Eureka for service discovery and Spring cloud gateway for routing. I would want to auto-route for the number of services I am having.

For example if one service 'eureka-client' registers to Eureka, and for routing with Spring Cloud Gateway, I've to create a route all by myself for each service like following.

```
  routes:
  - id: eureka-client
    uri: lb://eureka-client
    predicates:
    - Path=/eureka-client/**
```

With a few services that's acceptable but I might get hundreds of services in the end. And each has to write its own route in Spring Cloud Gateway. I have used spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true and doesn't solve the issue. Basically I am trying to eliminate the routes config in the yaml file.

Is there a way to provide auto routing from Spring Cloud Gateway to each service from Eureka?

Reference: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#discoveryclient-route-definition-locator

I am getting 404 as it was not able to get the proper routing
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved just by using the following properties
If you are using **application.properties**:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id: true
```

Or the following if you are using **application.yml**

```
  cloud:
    gateway:
     discovery:
       locator:
         enabled: true
           lower-case-service-id: true
```

And you don't need to explicitly specify the routes.

Answer (score 1):

The auto routing configuration is described in:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#the-discoveryclient-route-definition-locator

In case of Eureka Netflix client, the required dependency must be added in `pom.xml`, it must be enabled in the main app class (@EnableEurekaClient) and the required properties must be specified in `applications.yml`:

```
eureka:
    client:
        fetchRegistry: true
        registerWithEureka: false
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://localhost:port/eureka
    instance:
        preferIpAddress: true
```

In order to enable the gateway with services in lower case, add:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: gateway service
    cloud:
        gateway:
            discovery:
                locator:
                    enabled: 'true'
                    lower-case-service-id: 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make the gateway aware of the eureka server with this

**eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://user:pass@localhost:8761/eureka**

And then prevent the gateway from registering itself to eureka

**eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false**

Setting the second option to false is important as it causes 404 errors with loadbalancing using lb:servicename structure.

Comment: It doesn't change anything if the gateway is itself an eureka client. I tested the both cases and didn't lead to the expected result

Answer (score -2):

Try to access with upper-case url like:

```
<localhost>:<port>/EUREKA-CLIENT/<path>
```

Alternatively, you can set this:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true
```